# Do wide dependency and shuffle always occur at the same time in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, dependencies, shuffle

I am reading a spark book, and can hardly understand one sentence below. To me, I cannot imagine a case which is wide dependency, but we don't need shuffle. Can anyone give me an example?

"In certain instances, for example, when Spark already knows the data is partitioned in a certain way, operations with wide dependencies do not cause a shuffle." -- "High Performance Spark" by Holden Karau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RDD dependencies are actually in terms of partitions and how partitions are created.

Note: *Below definitions are for ease of understanding:*

If each of the partitions of an RDDs are created from only one partition of a single RDD, then it is a **narrow dependency**.

On the other hand, if a partition in a RDD is created from more than one partition(from same or different RDD), then it is a **wide dependency**.

Shuffle operation is required **whenever data required to create a partition is not at one place**(that means, it has to be taken from different locations/partitions).

If data is already **grouped in one or more partitions(using operations like groupBy, partitionBy etc)**, you just have to take the corresponding items from each of the partitions and merge them. In this case, shuffle operation is not necessary.

For more details refer [this](https://github.com/rohitvg/scala-spark-4/wiki/Wide-vs-Narrow-Dependencies#visual-narrow-dependencies-vs-wide-dependencies), especially the visual example images.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I may wrong, but in your linked example, it just demonstrates join can sometimes be narrow dependency. But still to me, the wide dependency must have a shuffle (F -> G), right?

Comment: In the diagram, B -> G doesn't require shuffle only F -> G does. That is because the `groupBy` between A -> B will already have grouped the data. So you don't have to group it again when joining with F thus doesn't require a shuffle. But in case of C->D, D->F and E->F, data is grouped so it requires shuffle operation.

Comment: F->G is wide dependency, and requires shuffle, which is my original question.

Comment: Ok, Assume, in that diagram, instead of `union` between D and E if it was a `join` operation, then there would be a shuffle between D and E to produce F. After that there wouldn't be any shuffle between F -> G (because F will have been grouped already in the join between D and E). That means even though B->G and F->G form a wide dependency, shuffle operation will not be necessary because both B and F are grouped before.

Comment: Hey "code", thanks for your answers. It is a little repeated but do you think in your last assumption, F->G is wide dependency. To me likely, not.

Comment: Yes, F->G is indeed a wide dependency! As I have explained in my answer, each partition in G is dependent on more than one partitions in F. (This is what dependency means, it's not between actual RDDs)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have difficulty to understand that since F->G is a many-to-many mapping (wide dependency), why there is no shuffle needed.

Comment: That's because the records in F are already grouped and saved in appropriate partitions, according to my initial assumption(instead of union, if it was a join). That means the location of all the matching records in F for a record in B can be easily obtained and doesn't require searching(thus avoiding a shuffle operation).

Comment: I see what you mean. But spark by default don't preserve the partition right? So do we need to manually tell spark don't shuffle when F->G? I mean how spark determines if the job needs shuffle or not?

Comment: Spark does store metadata about the RDDs and partitions including the information required to recompute them, the way the records are partitioned etc. Based on this metadata, spark automatically decides whether a shuffle is required or not. We don't have to manually tell the spark.

Comment: Take join for example, even two RDD is already partitioned, it still possible be distributed in different nodes . so you have to make sure data cached on the same machine to avoid shuffle?